# Node template only on specific page (Drupal 7)

Tags: theming

I've been reading through a ton of Drupal 7 theming docs but can't seem to find my answer.

Here's what I'm trying to do. I have two content types `article` and `feature`.

Nodes of *both* content types are displayed on my /blog page via the Views module. All working great so far.

When the node of type `article` is listed, it uses the node--article.tpl.php template, and when a node of type `feature` is listed on the blog listing page, is uses node--feature.tpl.php.

This is all as expected, *BUT* for `feature` types, I want to display the node--article.tpl.php template *only* on the /blog page, and use node--feature.tpl.php (the default) for that type otherwise.

In other words, I'd like to keep the templates separate, but use the same template for both `article` and `feature` types on the blog listing page (node--article.tpl.php).

Is there way to create a node-page-specific template file (use this template for this node ONLY if on this page)?

Answer (score 8):

add template.php:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if (request_path() == 'specific/page') {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__specific';
  }
}
```

and create file node--specific.tpl.php in theme dir

Answer (score 0):

If you're using views why not just switch to field display rather than node display? You could probably then just copy your node--article.tpl.php to the right views tpl and it would just pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

While considered evil in certain circles, you could certainly put something like:

```
<?php

$foo=explode('/',$_GET['q']);

if ($foo[0]=='blog') {

    ALL YOUR BLOG SPECIFIC TEMPLATE PHP GOES HERE

} else {

    TEMPLATE PHP FOR EVERYWHERE ELSE GOES HERE

}
```

in your node template file.